# Minimum needs to Deploy SQL Server Integration Services 2008

Tags: deployment, ssis, package, execution

I would like to run SSIS 2008 packages on a server that does not have SQL Server 2008 installed on it.  I have a simple package to test the concept, but it fails to execute.  The return code is 9020 which I have not seen listed as a return code elsewhere.

I have copied the following files to the test server that does not have SQL Server 2008 installed on it:

```
SelfContainedSample.dtsConfig
Package.dtsx
DTExec.exe
```

I am attempting to run the package using a batch file.  The line in the batch file that runs the package is:

```
"%dtexecloc%\dtexec.exe" /FILE "%packagefolder%\Package.dtsx" /CONFIGFILE "%configfolder\SelfContainedSample.dtsConfig"  /CHECKPOINTING OFF  /REPORTING E >>%logfile%
set rc=%errorlevel%
```

I am wondering if there are other requirements that need to be satified to run an SSIS 2008 package on a server that does not have SQL Server 2008 on it?  .NET Runtime?  SSIS 2008 runtime?

Please share your advice if you have a solution or have met this issue before.

Answer (score 1):

The following is from a discussion about this topic on
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/134585b4-7960-4b1c-938b-d5421a4d0fdb

> SSIS is a server component. To run a
>   SSIS package you need to license and
>   install the full SSIS server, there is
>   no client only. A machine that hosts
>   SSIS packages must be licensed as a
>   full SQL Server, a CAL is not
>   sufficient.
>
> There is no remote execution
>   functionality built in. The common
>   workarounds are to use a SQL Agent job
>   or a development technology such as a
>   web service or web page to bridge the
>   gap between the server and client.

The Quote is from Darren Green (about 4 answers down on the discussion). Jamie Thomson gives a similar answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need the SQL Server server-side binaries. SSIS does not have to be running though.

I'm not sure if SSIS has to be installed as a component though, or just the general binaries.

We did some tests recently to work out what is needed for the "lightest" way to run SSIS

[KB 942176](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/942176) refers to the role of the SSIS service